# complex analysis limit 0/0 problems

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

How can ı proof  $\frac{0}{0}$ 
uncertainty with L Hospital rule ?
$$\lim_{z \longrightarrow i} \frac{z^2 + 1}{z - i} = \lim_{z \longrightarrow i} 2z =2i  $$

Comment: You don't need L'Hôpital's rule, just factor the numerator into $(z+i)(z-i)$

Comment: ohh thank you sir

Answer (score 1):

$\require{cancel}$That is *not* an indeterminate:$$\lim_{z\to i}\frac{z^2+1}{z-i}=\lim_{z\to i}\frac{(z+i)\cancel{(z-i)}}{\cancel{z-i}}=\lim_{z\to i}z+i=2i.$$

Comment: sorry not $z-1$. $z-i$

Comment: I've edited my answer.